# Обработка данных с сервера

Tags: javascript

Прилетает массив данных с сервера в виде:

```
[{id:0,userId:1, name:"Альбом 1"},{id:1,userId:1, name:"Альбом 2"}, {id:2,userId:2, name:"Album 1"}]
```

С помощью JS нужно организовать данные в таком виде:

```
[{userId:1,albums:[{id:0, name:"Альбом 1"},{id:1, name:"Альбом 2"}}],
{userId:2, albums:[{id:2, name:"Album 1"}]}]
```

Мое решение таково:

```
   function filterUsers(items) {
        const newArray = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (i === 0) newArray.push({ userId: items[i].userId, albums: [] });
            const length = newArray.length - 1;
            if (newArray[length].id === items[i].userId) {
                newArray[length].albums.push({ ...items[i], userId: null });
            } else {
                newArray.push({ userId: items[i].userId, albums: [{ ...items[i], userId: null }] })
            }
        }
        return newArray;

    }
```

Но мне сказали что код неопрятен. Как его улучшить?

```js
const data = [
  { id: 0, userId: 1, name: "Альбом 1"}, 
  { id: 1, userId: 1, name: "Альбом 2"}, 
  { id: 2, userId: 2, name: "Album 1"}
];

function filterUsers(items) {
  const newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) newArray.push({
      userId: items[i].userId,
      albums: []
    });
    const length = newArray.length - 1;
    if (newArray[length].userId=== items[i].userId) {
      newArray[length].albums.push({ ...items[i],
        userId: null
      });
    } else {
      newArray.push({
        userId: items[i].userId,
        albums: [{ ...items[i],
          userId: null
        }]
      })
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(filterUsers(data));
```

Comment: Вы бы лучше прямо спросили тех, кто сказал, что "неопрятен код"  в чём именно и как улучшить и почему они так считают. Может быть мы вам скажем что-то, а те, другие, скажут, что стало ещё хуже :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спросил, но ответ непонятен мне: "Лучше будет пройтись по албьомам и построить объект, где ключи это userid, а значение массив альбомов" Подобный обьект будет неудобен для итераций)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский скорее я не понял точно. Но вопрос остается актуальным, как сделать код лучше)

Comment: Лучше/хуже - категории субъективные. Сейчас код просто неправильный.

Comment: @Igor Детали? Для этого я и создал вопрос

Comment: Что "детали"? Вы не видите разницы между требуемым результатом и тем, что возвращает функция?

Comment: @Igor функция работает правильно, в ```id``` обьекта указывается id user. Поправил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = [
  { id: 0, userId: 1, name: "Альбом 1"}, 
  { id: 1, userId: 1, name: "Альбом 2"}, 
  { id: 2, userId: 2, name: "Album 1"}
];

function filterUsers(items) {
  const r = items.reduce((r, i) => ((r[i.userId] || (r[i.userId] = [])).push(i), r), {});
  return Object.entries(r).map(i => {
    const o = {userId: i[0], albums: i[1]};
    o.albums.forEach(a => delete a.userId);
    return o;
  });
}

console.log(filterUsers(data));
```